# Does GhostScript require a GPU?

Tags: pdf, gpu, ghostscript

I'm converting pdf to images using a nodejs package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/pdf2images-multiple

This works successfully in docker on two different local machines which both have Graphic Cards. However when I try to run this on a server in Google Cloud (which does not have a GPU). The following error occurs for particular pdf pages that have graphs:

`error:    message=Failed to convert page to image, killed=false, code=1, signal=null, cmd=gm convert -density 150 -quality 100 -sharpen 0x1.0 -trim  '/usr/src/app/1161115-30-1kabyqq.2bteimgqfr.pdf[7]' '/usr/src/app/pdfimages1161115-30-10uod6h.siy6pyzaor/1161115-30-1kabyqq-7.png', stdout=, stderr=gm convert: "gs" "-q" "-dBATCH" "-dMaxBitmap=50000000" "-dNOPAUSE" "-sDEVICE=pnmraw" "-dTextAlphaBits=4" "-dGraphicsAlphaBits=4" "-r150x150" "-dFirstPage=8" "-dLastPage=8" "-sOutputFile=/usr/src/app/gmxHC5iw" "--" "/usr/src/app/gm0tibSq" "-c" "quit" (child process quit due to signal 11).
gm convert: Postscript delegate failed (/usr/src/app/1161115-30-1kabyqq.2bteimgqfr.pdf).`

I've created an AWS instance with a GPU and this error does not occur. Looking to see if there's an Environment Variable that would be able to skip the GPU variant in GhostScript at least until Google Cloud gets GPUs or some alternative that I'm not seeing here.

The command in the error message called GraphicsMagick has documentation saying it doesn't use any GPU techniques.
http://www.graphicsmagick.org/FAQ.html#are-there-any-plans-to-use-opencl-or-cuda-to-use-a-gpu

Comment: I wouldn't have thought that GhostScript requires a GPU.  Anyway, I note that "child process quit due to signal 11" says that the child, I guess `gm`, crashed with a segfault.  I'm disinclined to think that that would be related to absence of a GPU, but I haven't enough information to rule that out.

Answer (score 1):

Ghostscript does not need, and indeed is not capable of using (beyond using X to display the bitmap) a GPU. There is some SIMD code, but you can compile without that, obviously I have no idea how the Ghostscript you are using was compiled.

For Linux, its often impossible to move a binary from one box to another, because the ABI differs between the two systems in terms of things like the C runtime. Also, if the executable has been compiled with shared libraries (many distributions insist on doing this) then differing versions of the shared libraries might cause problems.

My guess is that, rather than the presence or absence of a GPU, there is some significant difference between the Google Cloud Linux and the AWS Linux.

The best way to deploy Ghostscript on Linux is to build it from source on the machine you intend to use, this is especially true if you intend to put it on multiple machines with different configurations.